# How to reload my classes so that this stacktrace will disappear?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-rad

I've got a really strange error. This is the stacktrace that is coming from the application server (websphere 8):

```
JSPG0049E: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter_visa.jsp failed to compile : JSPG0225E: An error occurred at line: 7 in the statically included file: /includes/arendeprocess_card_header_inc.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter_visa.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter_5F_visa.java : 446 : The method isRo() is undefined for the type AnsokanInfo JSPG0225E: An error occurred at line: 8 in the statically included file: /includes/arendeprocess_card_header_inc.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter_visa.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter_5F_visa.java : 450 : The method isIsa() is undefined for the type AnsokanInfo JSPG0225E: An error occurred at line: 9 in the statically included file: /includes/arendeprocess_card_header_inc.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter_visa.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter_5F_visa.java : 454 : The method isIpea() is undefined for the type AnsokanInfo JSPG0225E: An error occurred at line: 10 in the statically included file: /includes/arendeprocess_card_header_inc.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter_visa.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter_5F_visa.java : 458 : The method isIsa() is undefined for the type AnsokanInfo
```

And a similar problem for another JSP page, it won't load the newly added methods:

```
JSPG0049E: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp failed to compile : JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 410 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 682 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_FORNAMN cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 414 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 690 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_EFTERNAMN cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 428 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 700 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_FORETAG cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 431 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 708 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_ORGNUMMER cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 439 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 716 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_ATTENTION cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 442 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 724 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_POSTADRESS cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 445 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 732 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_POSTNR cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 448 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 740 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_POSTORT cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 451 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 748 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_LANDKOD cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 497 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 799 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_TEL cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 500 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 807 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_FAX cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 503 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 815 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_EPOST cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 506 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 823 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_REFERENS cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 510 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 833 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_SOKANDE_I cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 526 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 859 : PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_SOKANDE_I_LAND cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 562 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 887 : The method getFormattedAdress() is undefined for the type PersonInfo JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 563 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 889 : The method getFormattedReferens() is undefined for the type PersonInfo JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 583 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 917 : The method getFormattedAdress() is undefined for the type PersonInfo JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 584 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 919 : The method getFormattedReferens() is undefined for the type PersonInfo JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 614 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 933 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_FORNAMN cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 615 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 941 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_EFTERNAMN cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 628 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 949 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_FORETAG cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 629 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 957 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_ORGNUMMER cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 633 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 965 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_ATTENTION cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 636 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 973 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_POSTADRESS cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 639 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 981 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_POSTNR cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 642 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 989 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_POSTORT cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 645 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 997 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_LANDKOD cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 679 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1036 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_TEL cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 682 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1044 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_FAX cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 685 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1052 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_EPOST cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 688 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1058 : PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_OMBUD_REFERENS cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 688 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1060 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_REFERENS cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 689 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1064 : PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_OMBUD_REFERENS cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 691 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1068 : PandoraFieldConstants.LABEL_OMBUD_FOR cannot be resolved JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 718 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1106 : The method getFormattedAdress() is undefined for the type PersonInfo JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 719 in the file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /arendeprocess_grunduppgifter.jsp C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\temp\PRVSTHV1510Node01\server1\PandoraArendeEar\PandoraArendeWeb.war\_arendeprocess_5F_grunduppgifter.java : 1108 : The method getFormattedReferens() is undefined for the type PersonInfo
```

But the methods it's complaining about are really in the classes and I've redeployed it and restarted the server. So it seems that some changes are not updated. What is the correct way to handle this? I can compile and clean the project but there's this runtime exception when I try access the JSP page. I use RAD 8 and WAS 8 and that's where the stacktrace appears.

### Update

I did not solve this yet. The environment is IBM RAD 8 (=Eclipse) and WAS (websphere) 8 and my JSP doesn't recognize the newly added method to my Java class. I suspect there is some kind of caching going on that won't enable me to reload my classes. I've tried deleting the temporary files from the JSP and restarting the server and also I've cleaned the project but the error still appears. What should I do?

### Update 2

I could remove one of the offending classes and instead get a noclassfounderror but that is not much better. The IBM RAD is not working for me, it would've been better to develop from the command prompt than an IDE that makes it impossible for you to do development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clean and build in your **IDE** rational application develope
*and pay attention to output for any errors "important"*

> http://www.coderanch.com/t/528330/vc/does-Project-Clean-do-Eclipse

Comment: [clean vs publish vs restart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319389/rad-rational-application-developer-clean-vs-publish-vs-restart)  and this  [What's Eclipse's Project->Clean is actually doing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/eclipses-project-clean)

Comment: I thought I already did that. I also have automatic republishing activated and I didn't have this problem before. I will follow your advice anyhow.

Comment: did you solved it yet if not would you please provide more detaild about the jsp it self i faced similar problem i might help you with it

Comment: It's working now and I can clean the project. I had build errors, that's why it didn't reload. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the temp work folder where JSP are converted to .Java file  during runtime of WAS app server.Then a take a clean build and deploy it and re start the server.

Comment: But it's not the JSP that is the problem it is the javabean class that is not reloading. I could delete the class and instead get a noclassfounderror still in error. Why is it not working?

Comment: How you are deploying application to app server? Using RAD? However, take a clean build and remove all the class files from app server caching/temp folder during compile time and this time deploy the application using WAS admin console.

Comment: Yes, I'm using RAD to deploy to websphere but it's not working. I could remove all .class files but now I get I classnotfounderror instead and RAD fails to build and fails to place and deploy those files to websphere. I shouldn't have to use the admin console since this was working well just before I fetched the changes from the SVN. Plus I don't know where to find the admin console for WAS 8. This never would have ahppened with JBoss and a proper IDE, the RAD is not working for me and has blocked me from doing my work for several days because of this and all I need to do is compile a file.

Comment: One other method is create the same project all over again in your RAD and deploy the application into WAS.

Comment: It's working now. I checked out the project from version control from scratch and got help from a colleague to make the appropriate RAD settings. There were some dependencies and some new updates via version control that fixed everything. Thank you for the help.